# Uncaught ReferenceError: Gallery is not defined in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am working on the cube gallery to display the cubes.
I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Gallery is not defined fiddle.jshell.net:722

How to fix the error?

My fiddle is also below:

http://jsfiddle.net/N3GTy/12/

Providing my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            /*
            |------------------------------------------|
            | MelonHTML5 - 3D Cube Gallery             |
            |------------------------------------------|
            | @author:  Lee Le (lee@melonhtml5.com)    |
            | @version: 1.02 (09 Jan 2013)             |
            | @website: www.melonhtml5.com             |
            |------------------------------------------|
            */
            Gallery = {
                _config: {
                    speed: 500,
                    size: 100,
                    lightbox: !0,
                    closeOnEsc: !0,
                    animation: "default",
                    slideshow: !1,
                    slideshow_speed: 3E3,
                    cube_speed: 1E3
                },
                lightbox_speed: 300,
                window_width: null,
                window_height: null,
                _cube_timeout: null,
                _gallery: null,
                _overlay: null,
                _lightbox: null,
                _current: null,
                _in_slideshow: !1,
                init: function() {
                    Gallery._buildContainer(!0, !0);
                    Gallery.window_width = $(window).width();
                    Gallery.window_height = $(window).height();
                    $(document).keydown(Gallery.Events.keyDown);
                    $(window).resize(Gallery.Events.windowResize);
                    Gallery._startCube()
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Gallery.setOptions({...})` before `Gallery` is even defined.

Comment: Place `Gallery.setOptions(..` *after* the code you've posted on your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply....its working now....can you tell me how to fix this error too Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null  http://jsfiddle.net/N3GTy/28/embedded/result/

Comment: Caused by this line: `selectors = document.getElementById('tabSelector').children;`. Basically, there is no element with an id of `tabSelector` so calling for its `children` would result in an error. Use developer tools in your browser to see what's going on (like Firebug in FF).